# Does independence necessarily mean uncorrelatedness?

Tags: probability, independence, correlation

We all know that two independent events are uncorrelated, don't we?

Nonetheless, we can find events that are correlated, yet they are independent such as the examples found on the [Suprious Correlations](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations) website$^*$.

Is there a problem here or is it just me who's missing a ring in the chain?

$^*$ The website is actually meant to show that correlation doesn't imply causality but I think we can agree that the variables shown are independent (i.e., the occurrence of one does not affect the occurrence of the other).

Comment: The proof that independence implies uncorrelated (and thus correlated implies dependent) is simple and easy to understand. In fact it immediately follows that correlation is a form of dependence. So, conceptually, any spurious correlation is a spurious dependence. It seems are mixing up a few things here. Empirical vs theoretical and (as mentioned below) causal vs statistical. But the real problem is you're artificially separating the basic concepts of dependence and correlation when it's right in the definitions that the latter is just a type of the former.

Comment: So when you go to a more complicated issue like a spurious regression, you forget to treat the two terms on the same footing. What we have here is essentially a model misspecification. You fit a bad model and the result is that the model says these variables that have nothing to do with one another are correlated. But guess what: the bad model also says that they're dependent, as it must.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So spurious correlation is spurious dependence, okay. Is there a way to distinguish the different possible relationships or dependencies (causal, stochastic, and others)? Also what's this empirical vs theoretical, is it a the way we define stochastic independence?

Comment: By empirical vs theoretical I mean that a spurious empirical (i.e measured) correlation can sometimes just be due to a statistical fluke and is in no way reflective of a theoretical (i.e. true underlying) dependence between the two variables. Again it's an issue of comparing apples to apples. Even if you know theoretically that there's no dependence, you can't necessarily complain if there's a convincing empirical correlation cause that could have happened by chance. You could complain if there were a theoretical correlation, (which should be mathematically impossible since corr -> dep).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay. Got it.

Comment: By *just* due to a statistical fluke I mean as a opposed to a confound or something where there's an actual problem with the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep *stochastic* independence distinct from *causal* independence.

Two random variables that are stochastically independent are uncorrelated by definition.

Two random variables that are causally independent ($A$ does not imply/causes $B$, nor vice versa) may be correlated.

It is also possible that some third random variables $C$ separately influences both $A$ and $B$, making them correlated.

Comment: Then doesn't causal independence imply stochastic independence? I think that this is what I fail to see...

Comment: Not necessarily. Let $\rightarrow$ denote "causal dependence". Suppose that $A \rightarrow B$ and $A \rightarrow C$ but $B \not\rightarrow C$. Then $B$ and $C$ may still be correlated because of $A$'s influence.

Comment: Still though, I feel like in most of the examples on the website I cited the variables are independent and there is a correlation

Comment: Stochastic independence without being uncorrelated exists: if covariance is not defined.

Comment: By independence here I mean statistically... since the outcome of one variable is not influenced by the outcome of the other

Comment: @drhab what do you mean by covariance not defined? Can this explain the correlation we see in the website examples?

Comment: Expectations of random variables do need not be properly defined. This is e.g. the case if $\mathbb EX_+=\mathbb EX_-=+\infty$. Then $\mathbb EX$ is not defined. A covariance is an expectation so is not necessarily defined. It can be that $X$ and $Y$ are independent but have no properly defined covariance. For being uncorrelated the covariance must take value $0$ so they are not uncorrelated by definition. I haven't looked at your question, but only to this answer.

Comment: @drhab, thanks, is this the only reason why stochastic independence does not imply uncorrelatedness? and how do we check if a covariance is defined or not?

Comment: It is indeed the only reason I can think of. No time anymore. Cheers